# Why do I get onto:explicit statements when querying onto:implicit statements in GraphDB?

Tags: sparql, graphdb

On querying statements from `onto:implicit` in GraphDB 10.0.0 using SPARQL I also get `onto:explicit` results. Here is an example:

```
select * from <http://www.ontotext.com/implicit> where { 
    ?s ?p ?o .
}
```

Gives me all statements with context `onto:implicit` AND `onto:explicit`.
Only when I add a `MINUS` command it returns only the `onto:implicit` statements.

```
select * from <http://www.ontotext.com/implicit> where { 
    ?s ?p ?o .
    minus{
        graph <http://www.ontotext.com/explicit> {
            ?s ?p ?o .
        }
    }
}
```

Why is that? Fyi: If I use `from named <http://www.ontotext.com/implicit>` not even the version with `MINUS` works.